# Gmail: move from trash to archive using script

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script

I'm trying to move Threads form the Trash to the Archive of GMail by GMAIL Service in Google Apps Script.
If I do this nothing happens:

```
var threads = GmailApp.getTrashThreads(0, 100);
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    threads[i].moveToArchive();
}
```

Do I make something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move to archive doesn't seem to work from trash. Please file an issue tracker report. However, as a workaround, this will do:

threads[i].moveToInbox().moveToArchive();

Although to be honest that code will be really slow and might time out. This will be *much* faster:

```
var threads = GmailApp.getTrashThreads(0, 100);
GmailApp.moveThreadsToInbox(threads);
GmailApp.moveThreadsToArchive(threads);
```

Comment: Thanks like this it worked and for shure its slow but it was just a test ;) Now I'm going to do it like you told me.

Comment: Issue 1711 is now fixed.